# Can I tell style-loader to load my global css before my CSS Modules?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, postcss, css-modules, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

Most of my site is using Bulma classes for some of my global UI styling, and I'd like to continue to use those classes within my components, but also be able to define CSS Modules for those components for custom per component tweaks.

Because of this, I added `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` to my project which has allowed me to use my Bulma classes in `className` and put my module classes in `styleName`. Ok, a little hacky feeling, but it's working. I've got a `global-styles.scss` file in a CSS directory that I'm loading into my main app component. This is where I'm importing Bulma, as well as defining any of my own global styles.

My issue is that my when my global styles and my module styles all get smashed together (via css-modules?) and injected into a style tag in the head (via style-loader?), my module styles get defined first, then my global styles.

I feel like the module styles are locally scoped and should always take precedence (load last), even if I'm loading both global and scoped styles in the same component. For example, in one component I'm using Bulma's `.navbar` classes, but I'm also defining my own `.navbar` class in my CSS Module for that component, and I'm applying both to the same element in my component.

Is there anyway I can specify what order to build the style tag? Between all of these plugins I'm just lost, then when you throw Gatsby's plugin abstraction on top of it and it's all very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain of what was causing the issue, but it seems to pertain to Gatsby.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-two/#component-css

> Tip: This part of the tutorial has focused on the quickest and most straightforward way to get started styling a Gatsby site — importing standard CSS files directly, using gatsby-browser.js. In most cases, the best way to add global styles is with a shared layout component.

Their recommended approach is to import your global files in your layout component. This was loading my globals after my modules. However, creating a `gatsby-browser.js` file, and importing my globals there is loading my styles in the intended order.